# What thing does Beverly show to Ben in a classroom?

Tags: it-chapter-two

In [*IT Chapter Two* (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_Chapter_Two), Beverly meets Ben alone in a classroom.

> **Ben**: Are you smoking in school?
>
> [Beverly shows something on the ceiling; pictured below.]
>
> **Beverly**: Secret hideout. Don't tell anyone.

What thing does she show to him in a classroom?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Looks like a disabled smoke detector.

To me, that looks like a smoke detector that’s been disabled — or tampered with in some way to disable it — since it’s opened instead of sealed closed.

In the context of the dialogue, “secret hideout” simply means a classroom she found where either the smoke detector was disabled or she was able to disable it with anyone noticing so students could sneak a smoke inside the building without getting caught — or busted — by a smoke detector going off.